# linking c++ sources in iPhone project

Tags: c++, iphone, linker

I have a single cpp file added to my iPhone project with a .cpp extension, but I'm seeing errors when linking like:

> operator new[](unsigned long)", referenced from:
>
> ___gxx_personality_sj0", referenced from:

I thought as long as I named the cpp files with .cpp or .mm it would do the right thing, do I need to add some linker flags?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Select the file in the project browser, and press `cmd-i` to bring up the info window for the file in question. Set File Type to `sourcecode.cpp.cpp` should do it.

Alternatively right click on your project, add new file, select C++ source, then copy and paste the content.

In light of the build log, try adding the following linker flags:

```
-cclib -lstdc++
```

[This might be because `gcc` is being used to link, not `g++`](http://osdir.com/ml/programming.swig/2004-10/msg00118.html).

Comment: hmm, the .cpp file was already sourcecode.cpp.cpp, the associated header file was .c.h and I updated it to sourcecode.cpp.h but that didn't seem to help any.  Any ideas?

Comment: Hrmph, then perhaps you can try the alternative route, of adding a c++ file via add new file, and just copy-pasting the content?

Perhaps your problem is related to linking, are you using any libraries which aren't linked by default?

Comment: Adding the linker flags worked, for some reason I thought xcode did that magic for you depending on what the name of the file was.  The is a static lib so maybe that has something to do with it.